Subtracting overlapping 2D mesh with Python using Blender API
Supposing I have two 2D mesh objects, A and B.
I would like to programmatically subtract the overlapping portion of one from another.
I am almost there, just need to fix two problems:

The point of intersection has no edges.
There are random edges where there should not be any.

What causes this?
Screenshots and script code shown below.
EDIT: I'm a dingus, forgot to upload the file >.<

before

after
It is clear that there are the following problems:

The newly added vertex at the point of intersection has no edges
there are random edges where they should not be any
intersecting edges not deleted



script1
import bpy
import bmesh
from collections import defaultdict
import mathutils
from mathutils.geometry import intersect_line_line_2d
from mathutils import Vector


# convert_vertex_to_local_coords
#   Converts a vertex from one object's local space to that of another.
def convert_vertex_to_local_coords(source_obj, target_obj, vertex):
    # Convert the vertex from the source object's local space to world space
    world_coords = source_obj.matrix_world @ vertex
    
    # Convert the world space coordinates to the target object's local space
    local_coords = target_obj.matrix_world.inverted() @ world_coords
    
    return local_coords

# move_vertex_to_global_point
#   Converts global coordinates of a vertex to an object's local space.
def move_vertex_to_global_point(obj, vertex, global_point):
    # Convert global coordinates to local coordinates
    local_point = obj.matrix_world.inverted() @ global_point
    
    # Assign the local coordinates to the vertex
    vertex.co = local_point

# edge_intersect_2d
#   (boolean) Determines if two edges intersect, returning `True` with the point of intersection,
# or `False`, `None` if not.
def edge_intersect_2d(edge1, edge2, tolerance=1e-6):
    def vector_between_points(p1, p2):
        return p2 - p1
    
    def is_point_on_segment(p, segment_start, segment_end, tolerance=1e-6):
        segment_vector = segment_end - segment_start
        point_vector = p - segment_start
        cross_product = point_vector.x * segment_vector.y - point_vector.y * segment_vector.x  # Scalar cross product in 2D
        if abs(cross_product) > tolerance:
            return False
        dot_product = point_vector.dot(segment_vector)
        if dot_product < 0 or dot_product > segment_vector.length_squared:
            return False
        return True
    
    p1, p2 = edge1
    q1, q2 = edge2

    r = vector_between_points(p1, p2)
    s = vector_between_points(q1, q2)

    cross_r_s = r.x * s.y - r.y * s.x  # Scalar cross product in 2D
    q_p = q1 - p1
    cross_q_p_r = q_p.x * r.y - q_p.y * r.x  # Scalar cross product in 2D

    if cross_r_s == 0:
        if cross_q_p_r == 0:
            return (False, None)
        else:
            return (False, None)

    t = (q_p.x * s.y - q_p.y * s.x) / cross_r_s  # Scalar cross product in 2D
    u = (q_p.x * r.y - q_p.y * r.x) / cross_r_s  # Scalar cross product in 2D

    if 0 <= t <= 1 and 0 <= u <= 1:
        intersection = p1 + t * r
        if is_point_on_segment(intersection, p1, p2) and is_point_on_segment(intersection, q1, q2):
            return (True, intersection)
    
    return (False, None)

# get_edge_vertices_in_world_coords_2d
#   Converts two edge vertices from object-local coordinates to global coordinates.
def get_edge_vertices_in_world_coords_2d(obj, edge):
    vert1_world = obj.matrix_world @ edge.verts[0].co
    vert2_world = obj.matrix_world @ edge.verts[1].co

    vert1_2d = Vector((vert1_world.x, vert1_world.y))
    vert2_2d = Vector((vert2_world.x, vert2_world.y))

    return vert1_2d, vert2_2d

# add_edge_to_mesh
#   Adds an edge between 2 vertices to the mesh provided.
def add_edge_to_mesh(bm, v1, v2):
    v1_local = bm.verts.new(v1)
    v2_local = bm.verts.new(v2)
    bm.verts.index_update()
    bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table()
    new_edge = bm.edges.new([v1_local, v2_local])
    bm.edges.index_update()
    
    return new_edge

# is_inside_mesh_2d
#   Determine if a point is inside a given polygon.
def is_inside_mesh_2d(point, obj):

    x, y = point.x, point.y
    vertices = obj.data.vertices
    num_vertices = len(vertices)
    inside = False

    p1 = vertices[0]
    for i in range(num_vertices + 1):
        p2 = vertices[i % num_vertices]
        if y > min(p1.co.y, p2.co.y):
            if y <= max(p1.co.y, p2.co.y):
                if x <= max(p1.co.x, p2.co.x):
                    if p1.co.y != p2.co.y:
                        xinters = (y - p1.co.y) * (p2.co.x - p1.co.x) / (p2.co.y - p1.co.y) + p1.co.x
                    if p1.co.x == p2.co.x or x <= xinters:
                        inside = not inside
        p1 = p2

    return inside

# split_edge_at_intersection
#   Splits an edge at the point specified.
def split_edge_at_intersection(objA, objB, bm, edge_index, intersection_point):    
    edge = bm.edges[edge_index]
    v1 = edge.verts[0]
    v2 = edge.verts[1]
    
    # Check if v1 or v2 is inside objB
    v1_in_objB = is_inside_mesh_2d(objA.matrix_world @ v1.co, objB)
    v2_in_objB = is_inside_mesh_2d(objA.matrix_world @ v2.co, objB)
    
    # Move the vertex that is inside objB to the intersection point
    if v1_in_objB:
        move_vertex_to_global_point(objA, v1, intersection_point)
    elif v2_in_objB:
        move_vertex_to_global_point(objA, v2, intersection_point)
    else:
        print("This is FUBAR.")
    
    bm.verts.index_update()
    bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table()
    
    return edge

# is_edge_entirely_inside_mesh
#   Returns true if and only if both vertices of an edge are entirely within another object.
def is_edge_entirely_inside_mesh(source_obj, target_obj, edge):
    v1 = convert_vertex_to_local_coords(source_obj, target_obj, edge.verts[0].co)
    v2 = convert_vertex_to_local_coords(source_obj, target_obj, edge.verts[1].co)
    #print(f"{edge.verts[0].co},{edge.verts[1].co}\t{v1},{v2}")
    return (is_inside_mesh_2d(v1, target_obj) and is_inside_mesh_2d(v2, target_obj))

# replace_edges_within_2d
#   
def replace_edges_within_2d(objA, objB):
    meshA = objA.data
    meshB = objB.data

    bm_a = bmesh.new()
    bm_a.from_mesh(meshA)
    bm_a.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
    bm_a.edges.ensure_lookup_table()

    bm_b = bmesh.new()
    bm_b.from_mesh(meshB)
    bm_b.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
    bm_b.edges.ensure_lookup_table()

    intersection_points = []

    for edge1 in bm_a.edges:
        v1, v2 = get_edge_vertices_in_world_coords_2d(objA, edge1)
        for edge2 in bm_b.edges:
            v3, v4 = get_edge_vertices_in_world_coords_2d(objB, edge2)
            intersects, intersection_point = edge_intersect_2d((v1, v2), (v3, v4))
            if intersects:
                local_intersection_point = objA.matrix_world.inverted() @ Vector((intersection_point.x, intersection_point.y, 0))
                split_edge_at_intersection(objA, objB, bm_a, edge1.index, local_intersection_point)
                intersection_points.append(local_intersection_point)

    edges_within_mesh = [edge for edge in bm_a.edges if is_edge_entirely_inside_mesh(objA, objB, edge)]
    bmesh.ops.delete(bm_a, geom=edges_within_mesh, context='EDGES')

    edges_within_mesh = [edge for edge in bm_b.edges if is_edge_entirely_inside_mesh(objB, objA, edge)]
    new_edges = []

    for edge in edges_within_mesh:
        v1, v2 = get_edge_vertices_in_world_coords_2d(objB, edge)
        local_v1 = objA.matrix_world.inverted() @ Vector((v1.x, v1.y, 0))
        local_v2 = objA.matrix_world.inverted() @ Vector((v2.x, v2.y, 0))
        new_edge = add_edge_to_mesh(bm_a, local_v1, local_v2)
        new_edges.append(new_edge)

    # Close off the shape by adding edges between intersection points and the first/last new edges
    if intersection_points:
        first_intersection = intersection_points[0]
        last_intersection = intersection_points[-1]
        
        # Connect intersection points to the new edges
        bm_a.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
        bm_a.edges.ensure_lookup_table()
        
        first_new_edge = new_edges[0] if new_edges else None
        last_new_edge = new_edges[-1] if new_edges else None

        if first_new_edge:
            first_new_edge_v1 = bm_a.verts.new(first_intersection)
            first_new_edge_v2 = first_new_edge.verts[0]

            bm_a.edges.new([first_new_edge_v1, first_new_edge_v2])

        if last_new_edge:
            last_new_edge_v1 = bm_a.verts.new(last_intersection)
            last_new_edge_v2 = last_new_edge.verts[1]

            bm_a.edges.new([last_new_edge_v1, last_new_edge_v2])

        bm_a.verts.index_update()
        bm_a.edges.index_update()

    bm_a.to_mesh(meshA)
    bm_a.free()
    bm_b.free()

# subtract_mesh_2d
#   Subtract meshes and find intersecting edges
def subtract_mesh_2d(objA, objB):
    print(f"Subtracting {objA.name} from {objB.name}")
    replace_edges_within_2d(objA, objB)
    
    
    
# Get the collection objects
col1 = bpy.data.collections.get('countries')
col2 = bpy.data.collections.get('lakes')


objX = col1.objects.get('Kenya')
objY = col2.objects.get('Nyanza')
subtract_mesh_2d(objX, objY)

This is a different approach to an earlier question of mine; due to never being able to solve that with built-in tools I am instead trying it solve it programmatically.
Thanks for any light you can shed; you have no idea how long I have been at this frustrating dead end!


I think you wanna look into the built-in mathutils.BVHTree object. I'm not 100% sure it will be a silver bullet fix for your issue, but that's specifically what it's designed for. Finding overlaps, raycasts etc between meshes.

Ah, so I had recently discovered BVHTrees!  And was very much looking forward to to using them for the next phase: efficiently detecting overlaps of all objects in one collection (e.g. countries, in this example) with another (e.g. lakes).
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.bvhtree.html#mathutils.bvhtree.BVHTree.overlap looks very promising.
While it is evidently much, much better at detecting, I am still on my own with regards to actually making the modifications, correct?

Well, yes. But also I think you can replace a huge chunk of the code you have already for checking overlaps with a few lines. Convert your bm objects into a BVHTree then just do a bvh1.overlap(bvh2). That should return two list of indices of vertices that overlap in between both trees. Then just delete the non-intersecting geo.

Not an expert by any means but it looks like you're only working with vertices and edges, so a BVHTree (BVH stands for Bounding Volume Hierarchy) is not really suited for that. You can however use a KDTree (k-dimensional) structure. Thankfully it is also supported by Blender https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.kdtree.html
